# Using C# lambda to find not matching elements in collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two collections that I get from functions:

```
IEnumerable<InventoryItem> inventoryItems = get();
IEnumerable<InventoryItem> relatedItems = get();
```

I want to assign related items to each inventory item. But, related item can't match the inventory item itself. Meaning inventory item cant have itself for related item.

I am trying to skip the overlapping elements in the collection this way:

```
foreach (var item in inventoryItems)
    {
      InventoryItem item1 = item;
      relatedItems.SkipWhile(x => x.RelatedItems.Contains(item1)).ForEach(i => item1.RelatedItems.Add(i));
      Save(item);
    }
```

This does not seem to work. Do any of you Linq user have any better suggestions.
The problem that I have is with `SkipWhile(x => x.RelatedItems.Contains(item1))` part. The other part works when matching items regardless if they overlap

Comment: May be it's just me but it's unclear what are the rules for grouping your items. Question would win if you added examples of actual values/result.

Comment: For each item there are related items. Those related items can't contain the item they are assigned to.

Comment: Side note: "A related to B" hence "B *not* related to A" seem to be quite strange "relationship"... Maybe there is better name for it.

Comment: It is one way relation. Viewing item A will show related item B, but viewing item B will not show item A

Comment: Simply not following how you want to map the items in `relatedItems` collection to items in `inventoryItems`.. Code which doesn't work, obviously doesn't help in understanding the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

`Where` with negative condition should filter out the only item you don't need (note that comapison with `!=` may need to be replaced with some other condition that check item identity)

```
    item1.RelatedItems = relatedItems
         .Where(x => !x.RelatedItems.Any(r => r!= item1)).ToList();
```

Comment: that works, but without the restriction: relatedItems.ForEach(i => item.RelatedItems.Add(i));

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetNotMatchingElements<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection1, IEnumerable<T> collection2)
    {
        var combinedCollection = collection1.Union(collection2);
        var filteredCollection = combinedCollection.Except(collection1.Intersect(collection2));
        return filteredCollection;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand, but if I do, this should work:

```
foreach (var invItem in inventoryItems)
{
    invItem.RelatedItems = relatedItems
        .Where(relItem => !relItem.RelatedItems.Contains(invItem)));
    Save(invItem);
}
```